# Ironpython in spotfire to change the active datatable or visualization?

Tags: error-handling, ironpython, spotfire

I was hoping someone would be able to help me figure out how to change the currently active datatable and/or visualization using IronPython in Spotfire. I currently have a button configured to run an IronPython script that both moves to another page in my dashboard as well as generates a cursor to mark a row in a data table on that page (there are multiple data tables and visualizations on this new page).

I've been using the following cursor script from https://community.tibco.com/s/article/How-to-Mark-Rows-based-on-Document-Property-Value-in-TIBCO-Spotfire-Using-IronPython-Scripting

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

selectedValue=Document.Properties["propertyName"]
#Create a cursor to refer a column which will have the values
table=Document.Data.Tables["tableName"]
cursor = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(table.Columns["columnName"])

rowCount = table.RowCount
#empty indexset
rowsToMark = IndexSet(rowCount,False)
for row in Document.ActiveDataTableReference.GetRows(cursor):
   rowIndex = row.Index
   if cursor.CurrentValue == selectedValue:
       rowsToMark.AddIndex(rowIndex)
       
Document.ActiveMarkingSelectionReference.SetSelection(RowSelection(rowsToMark),table)
```

The script works fine when my desired data table is the active table; however, for some reason, the button sometimes targets another data table ("notTableName") on the visualization that is not "tableName" resulting in an error saying notTableName.columnName does not exist. I've been using Document.ActivePageReference to switch pages and that seems to always get me to my target page unless this error occurs.
I've been able to trace the error to the page switch itself so I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix/change what data table or visualization is active so that I can ensure the correct values are available for marking script to always work.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the change of page does, as that is not in the script.
If you want to mark a specific table, rather than the one that is currently active (i.e. selected) you can substitute this line:

```
for row in Document.ActiveDataTableReference.GetRows(cursor):
```

with this:

```
for row in table.GetRows(cursor):
```

given that table is already defined in your script and is the table your column refers to.